# Как открыть модальное окно по id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button id="myBtn" class="button_free d-block d-lg-none"  type="button">
ar modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
// var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closee")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Есть модальное окно , которое открывается по нажатию на кнопку, но вот таких кнопок много. Я не хочу немного хардкодить и ставить id каждому и копировать js код несколько раз . Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на любую кнопку, открывалась модальное окно. Сейчас открывается только при нажатии на первую , но это то понятно

сделал вот так , но не уверен , что это правильно

```
 jQuery('.button_free').click(function() {
      jQuery('#myModal').css("display", "block");
    });
```

Comment: задаешь один какой-то класс для всех кнопок и на этот класс вешаешь обраточик открытия

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. сделал при помощи jquery , но не уверен , что так делают , но работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.click-me').click(_ => alert('open modal'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click-me">Button 1</button>
<button class="click-me">Button 2</button>
<button class="click-me">Button 3</button>
<button class="click-me">Button 4</button>
<button class="click-me">Button 5</button>
```